# Check for increased font size

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, font-size

Can I check with jQuery whether the User increased the font size and bind a function to this event, to recalculate some stuff when this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, you can't do this directly.

The closest you can get I believe is attaching to the `resize` event of an element you know this would have an effect on.  You can do this by [grabbing the resize plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/), then attaching the event to an element font-size changing would resize, like this:

```
$("#myDiv").resize(function() {
 //recalc
});
```

The resize plugin just makes the [`.resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) handler available on pretty much any element.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this is totally browser handling. You can not catch an event if the font size increases, there is no such event unfortunately.